# AWS CLI Version Conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am having issues connecting to S3 using AWS CLI, while upgrading I see the error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
boto3 1.21.28 requires botocore<1.25.0,>=1.24.28, but you have botocore 1.29.11 which is incompatible.
boto3 1.21.28 requires s3transfer<0.6.0,>=0.5.0, but you have s3transfer 0.6.0 which is incompatible.
```

How can it be resolved? Do I revert back to the previous version of AWS CLI?

Comment: How are you installing/upgrading awscli?

Comment: You need to find versions of the libraries that are compatible with each other.

Comment: I am using Windows & used pip. How can i find what versions are compatible with each other & create a working environment ?

Comment: Use the Windows installer from: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/